# Put Button Horizontally At the Vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have an android application where it displays two textbox in a vertical linear layout. I would like to put a button at the right side (horizontally) between the two textbox.  Is there any way to do this but to maintain the linear layout of the two textbox? Below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vpo_mirTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantityTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout

Comment: You can use two nested linear layout to inside the parent linear layout, like inside the parent, there is first linear layout that contains one TextView and Button and another linear layout that contains one TextView and Button if you want one button next to each of your textview, Or if you want to use only one button you can modify according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use any parent layout and then use linear layout and button. You can do this in any layout but I am showing you in constraint layout as it is the easiest one.

**I have added background color to the textView so that they are visible**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vpo_mirTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantityTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_error"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ll_textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ll_textView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ll_textView"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is how it looks**
[image: button aligned horizontally with a linear layout with 2 text vertical textview]